How to Run Behave BDD Framework from Feature File Using Run Button?
Body:
I’m trying to run the Behave BDD framework directly from the feature file using the run button. However, when I click the run button, I encounter the error: “Nothing here.” The script runs perfectly fine from the command line.
Steps I’ve Taken:
Verified that the script runs without issues from the command line.
Checked the feature file and step definitions for any errors.
Issue:
Clicking the run button on the feature file results in the error: “Nothing here.”
Question: How can I successfully run the Behave BDD framework by clicking the run button on the
feature file?
configuration
  └── config.ini
features
  ├── Pages
  ├── Steps
  └── *.feature

enter image description here
How can I successfully run the Behave BDD framework by clicking the run button on the feature file?

Do you have any BDD related plugins installed in your IDE? You need Gherkin plugin enabled in the settings

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-behave.html

@MonicaVoinescu yupp, Ihave Gherkin plig-in installed in my pyCharm IDE
